# How do I select a single grouped column from a dataview?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, dataview

I have a data table `tblWorkList` with multiple columns: `RecordNr`, `GroupNum`, `Section`, `SubscriberID`, and quite a few others.

What I need to do is create a dataview or second datatable that is the equivalent of:

```
SELECT SubscriberID FROM tblWorkList GROUP BY SubscriberID;
```

I'm doing it in the application because I need this to end up in a dataview that will then be filtered based on multiple user inputs.  I have that part working.  I've spent several hours now beating my head against the internet trying to figure out how to do this, but I keep running up against errors in solutions that LOOK like they should work but end up failing spectacularly.  Although, that said, I'm VERY inexperienced with LINQ right now, so I'm sure I'm missing something pretty straightforward.

(The basic functionality is this: The table contains a list of records to be processed.  Basically, I need to take the table full of records, pull the subscriber IDs into a dataview, allow the user to filter that dataview down by a variety of methods (and providing the user a running count of the number of SubscriberID's matching the selected criteria), and when they're done, assign all of the records associated with the resulting `SubscriberID` collection to a specific analyst to be processed.)

All of the methods I've attempted to use to create the list or dataview of SubscriberID values are enclosed in this:

```
using (DataTable dt = dsWorkData.Tables["tblWorkData"])
```

The table `tblWorkData` contains approximately 23,000 records.

Here are several of my attempts.

Attempt 1 - Error is

> Parameter may not be null.   Parameter: source'

```
var result1 = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
              group row by row.Field<string>("SubscriberID") into grp
              select new { SubscriberID = grp.Key };

ShowMessage(result1.Count().ToString());
```

Attempt 2 - Error is

> 'Cannot implicitly convert anonymous type: string SubscriberID to DataRow'

```
EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> query =
    from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
    group row by row.Field<string>("SubscriberID") into grp
    select new { SubscriberID = grp.Key };
```

Attempt 3 - Error is

> 'The [third] name 'row' does not exist in the current context.'

```
EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> query2 =
    from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
    group row by row.Field<string>("SubscriberID") into grp
    select row;
```

Attempt 4 - same error as Attempt 1:

```
DataTable newDt = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => new { SubscriberID = r["SubscriberID"] })
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(r => r["SubscriberID"]).First())
    .CopyToDataTable();

MessageBox.Show(newDt.Rows.Count.ToString());
```

Attempt 5 - same error as Attempt 1:

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("SubscriberID"));

MessageBox.Show(result.Count().ToString());
```

Attempt 6 - same error as Attempt 1:

```
var results = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(g => g["SubscriberID"])
                                          .Select(x => x.First());
MessageBox.Show(results.Count().ToString());
```

So can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here, or at least point me in the right direction? I don't really care WHICH approach gets used, for the record, as long as there's a way to do this.

Comment: Your SQL query is really using `GROUP BY` to do `DISTINCT`, so just use the LINQ `Distinct`: `dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("SubscriberID") ).Distinct()`.

Comment: PS Your first error implies that `dt` is `null` - `source` is the parameter name to `AsEnumerable`.

Comment: You can filter the nulls by adding a WHERE to your query.

Comment: NetMage - Thanks, I'll do that tomorrow.  As to dt, I checked when I ran into the error the first time, and the table I'm referencing absolutely has records - just before that code is run, a count of the total records in the table is displayed onscreen.

Comment: jdwent - there are actually no nulls in that field.  I checked, but I'll play with it more tomorrow if NetMage's fix doesn't pan out.  Thanks!

Comment: NetMage - that worked!  And yeah, half the problem was dt - the table I needed was WorkList, not WorkData.  Stupid tunnel vision!  Anyway, thanks!  EDIT: I would flag your comment as the answer, but apparently I don't have enough rep to do that yet, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was a pair of comments from NetMage:

> Your SQL query is really using `GROUP BY` to do `DISTINCT`, so just use the LINQ `Distinct`: `dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("SubscriberID") ).Distinct()`.
>
> PS Your first error implies that `dt` is `null` - `source` is the parameter name to `AsEnumerable`.